# Typescript \n is replaced with %0A

Tags: typescript, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm creating a custom Azure pipeline task using Typescript.

I got these lines:

```
var errorsAndWarnings = await getBuildErrors(pipelineRunId, true);
tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Succeeded, "Finished Service Operation\n" + errorsAndWarnings);
```

The value of `errorsAndWarnings` is "No Errors". So what I expected to see is:

> Finished Service Operation

> No Errors

But what I actually got was:

> Finished Service Operation%0ANo Errors

How can I make the `\n` create a new line in the string?